Linear combinations of solutions to linear recurrences
I am working through MIT's Mathematics for Computer Science through OCW. Currently on homogeneous linear recurrences. A link with the course textbook is attached. My question is with the proof for the ability to include all linear combinations of solutions, found from the characteristic equation, as solutions. The text proves this on page 14-15 of the linked PDF.
My question: line two of the proof.
Proof image
h(n) = sf(n) + tg(n)
     = s(a_1(f(n-1)) + ... + a_d(f(n-d))) + t(a_1(g(n-1)) + ... + a_d(g(n-d)))

Following this, the terms a_1...a_d are grouped together:
a_1(sf(n-1)+tg(n-1)) + ... + a_d(sf(n-d)+tg(n-1))

Why are we expanding f(n) and g(n) as if they were themselves linear recurrences? I was under the impression that they were exponential functions? And even if they are linear recurrences, why are we assuming that the constant factors in front of each term are the same for f(n) and g(n).
Disclaimer: very new to all of this stuff, and currently very, very confused. My question probably doesn't even make much sense.

The problem hypothesizes that $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are both solutions to a homogeneous, linear recurrence. By this, it is meant that they are solutions to the same linear recurrence. I can see ambiguity, there, but imagine there is a homogeneous linear recurrence to which $f,g$ are solutions. That reading makes it clearer why they use the same coefficients $a_i$.

@user469053 That makes sense, thank you!! To me, however, this reveals that I’m maybe not too sure what exactly is meant by a solution. Do f and g represent exponential equations of the form r^n? If that is the case, then I don’t even see how we can take the first step of expanding them out to the form in line two.

Ah! I have just thought about it a little longer, and it makes sense! f and g are solutions, by definition, that meet the constraints imposed by the linear recurrence. An aha moment for me.
